# Camunda and Okta integration for SSO

Tags: integration, camunda, okta

I am building a workflow engine using camunda. I have made progress on it. But I want to make its admin panel such that it take authentication from OKTA where my other apps are present. I don't want to have separate username and passwords specific to camunda. I have no idea how to do that. Please give some ideas to achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know OKTA, but the general way of telling camunda do use a different Identity Management than the database default is to exchange the IdentityProvider. Its documented [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/identity-service/) for LDAP and should work similar for OKTA (though you'd have to write your own OKTA Provider for it).

A more reusable approach would be to use spring security with camunda and integrate OKTA with spring security ...

Comment: Basically what I have to do is, whenever any user lands on camunda login page, I have to redirect him to a particular okta's URL and then okta will authenticate and returns the USER object. Now, the problem is whenever I am getting a user object, I have to make sure it to be in camunda database entry and have to skip camunda login page. How to do that is the main concern ?